# Angular 4/5 simply client side for portability?

Tags: angular

I once fumbled a bit with Angular 1 for some hobby project and I just had a simple html page and some js files and was done.

Now I want to continue again and stumble upon Angular 4/5. It looks nice and interesting, but to me appears that all the examples use the Angular CLI together with Express / Node. And so the most simple example requires me to run a web server. Even if I don't have any serverside interaction I need a webserver. Am I overlooking something or is it impossible to just have a HTML file with some (precompiled by Angular) JS files in order to make it very portable?

Mind, I am not developing for some professinal business. Just an enthousiast that likes to tinker and create it's own stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overlooking a few items and missing some pieces, mainly:

- Angular-CLI and npm are for development, and not for direct deployment.
- After building a project with Angular CLI you can use the command `ng build` to create a `dist` bundle which will contain your single web page and javascript + assets.
- You can host the items inside the `dist` folder after building a project on any server with minimal tweaks (even apache, but you need to edit the .htaccess file to forward route params).

If you create a new project with Angular CLI with `ng new project-name`, you can immediate type `ng build` and see the results of a single `index.html` along with the javascript files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I couldn't see the wood for the trees anymore.

Comment: @avanwieringen For sure! Angular has become a lot more 'hefty' in general since 1, but the final result is a more compressed and makes building apps quicker once you learn it!